# Laravel Carbon Maatwebsite Format Date

Tags: laravel, php-carbon, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to format date with `Carbon` before importing my data due to the following reason

when importing dates they are changed to a value resembling this `101010`(example) even though the excel value looks like `01/01/1001`

Here is a [discussion](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel/issues/1832) on it however I have had no luck with there suggested ideas and am wondering if there are any other recommenadations or if I am missing something?

here is my import ClientsImport.php

```
public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new Client([
            'category' => $row[0],
            'referral_type' => $row[1],
            'first_name' => $row[2],
            'middle_initial' => $row[3],
            'last_name' => $row[4],
            'occupation' => $row[5], 
            'dob' => \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $row['6']),
            'email' => $row[7], 
            'cell_phone' => $row[8],
            'work_phone' => $row[9],
            'has_spouse' => $row[10],
            'spouse_first_name' => $row[11], 
            'spouse_middle_initial' => $row[12], 
            'spouse_last_name' => $row[13], 
            'spouse_occupation' => $row[14], 
            'spouse_dob' => \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $row['15']), 
            'spouse_email' => $row[16], 
            'spouse_cell_phone' => $row[17], 
            'spouse_work_phone' => $row[18], 
            'street_address' => $row[19],
            'city' => $row[20],
            'state' => $row[21],
            'postal_code' => $row[22], 
        ]);
    }
```

I have tried `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($row['6'])`
and I get this error `A non well formed numeric value encountered`

And also tried `\Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $row['6'])`
and I get this error `The separation symbol could not be found ↵The separation symbol could not be found`

Comment: But what values you sent to Carbon? `dd($row['6'])` or `dd($row['15'])` for example.

Comment: @alksejjj  the value sent looks like this `01/01/1001`, or it could be `01/01/2018` either way I get the same issue.

Comment: When you dump the values in `$row['6']` or some other date field, is it `01/01/2018` with leading zeros on the day and month, or is it `1/1/2018`?

Comment: thank you for the help, I actually ended up using a helper function to format the dates which brought up other issues which are outside the scope of this post